How to generate BPMN diagrams using `bpmn-js-cli` in Node.js environment?
I’d like to use bpmn-js-cli to programmatically generate BPMN diagrams (BPMN 2.0 XML) from JSON data in a Node.js environment. Currently, most examples for bpmn-js-cli appear to run in a browser context, interacting with a Modeler instance that renders a diagram to the DOM.
My questions:

Is it possible to run bpmn-js-cli commands in a pure Node.js environment (e.g., without a browser or DOM) to generate BPMN XML files?
If so, could you provide or point to a code snippet demonstrating how to:

Initialize the Modeler or a suitable equivalent in Node.js
Load or create an empty BPMN diagram
Use bpmn-js-cli commands to add BPMN elements (e.g., start events, user tasks, end events)
Finally, export the resulting diagram as BPMN XML



